# Custom bootstrap menu SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know the possibility or even a example of a menu as shown in the image below.

[image]

source http://webslidemenu.uxwing.com/demo/webslide/mobile-drawer-style-menu/01-megamenu-layout/index.html#

is this possible in SharePoint to have an menu like the above. i have checked the navigation or term set where we can set normally menu with 3 levels. but i couldn't find a reference for the above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good sample to customize BootStrap navigation menu in SharePoint Online for your reference:

[BootStrap Navigation](http://thomasdaly.net/2015/10/13/bootstrap-navigation-for-office-365-sharepoint-2013-using-jquery-and-rest/)

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks but what i need is a mega menu. is it possible with sharepoint ?

Comment: Hi, For SharePoint Online, the mega menu is not easy to achieve, as this at least need to modify the master page, but SharePoint Online not recommended to customize the master page as it is maintained by Microsoft

Comment: Thanks Jerry, we have a tool called shortpoint where we can add the css, java script codes to be added to this without changing the master page. It will work even if the menu items are taken from a list.